# Is there in-memory SQL database supporting replication/clustering?

Tags: sql, database, cluster-computing, in-memory-database, in-memory

Free and stable is the winner.

My plan is quite trivial - just put all the data in memory and use the cluster without changing the application code. Then, for persistence, I could just dump the data from nodes in a regular disk-access database.

The only thing is, that since I demand in-memory storage, there is no possibility of full data replication. I would like to copy the DB schema only and that in-memory DB manages all the joins consistently for me.

thank you in advance!

UPDATE:
I've found an open-source product likely to meet my requirements, it's [VoltDB](http://voltdb.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of interest, any particular reason why you 'demand' in-memory storage and can't just use a normal db server?

Comment: Such a reason could be that I intend an intranet deployment (with no decent data-center), but that's not the case. Actually, I know that there are pretty things like 'apache CouchDB' which work very fast; so is that the direction you would point me to?

Comment: I'd suggest you rethink and go with a standard db server, unless you have particular requirements that mean you need an in-memory db. From your question it sounds like you're looking for a solution to a problem (e.g. performance) and assuming in-memory db is that solution, without describing the problem. There are good in-memory dbs, but unless you really need them you're probably better off with a more standard solution.

Comment: This is just a comment/question, not an answer.

Comment: @abbas - have you heard of the Socratic method? ;)

Comment: Let me answer on his behalf :) I will use an in-memory database when I need to perform more than 7000 insert/update operations on the data. No free and normal database supports this much load. Whereas, in-memory database can withstand this much load.

Answer (score 1):

H2 Database also supports some kind of clustering.

Answer (score 0):

How about oracle's times ten
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/timesten/overview/index.html
Or maybe berkeley DB

Comment: Thanks, I'll check Berkeley DB

Comment: Berkeley DB is 'key-value' :) I looked for a relational DB with SQL interface

Comment: you might look at this - http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear to me.
You can have a look to [Timesten](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftimesten&rct=j&q=timesten&ei=TPbCTNf5EMn3sgbKw8XeCA&usg=AFQjCNElwMtCeYE9o7E_o5CX07nbGHfXPw&sig2=2LSFMz0VYCqeTveo091vGg&cad=rja) (now owned by ORACLE), it is based on SHMDB and provides a SQL interface.

MySQL cluster is also a kind of in-memory DB as when you commit, it means data are in memory of two nodes and not written on disk. But of course MySQL cluster will write all data on disk asynchronously to be able to backup and recover data after a crash.

Comment: Thank for 'Timesten', but I cannot find if it's available for free :)

Answer (score 0):

This product would also do the job as an in-memory cluster: 
http://terracotta.org

It also comes whit an adapter to java Quartz Scheduler, if you wanna handle some jobs to.

Answer (score 0):

- [MEMSQL](http://blog.memsql.com/memsql-community-edition/), its wire compatible (or drop in replacement) with MySQL.
- H2 is also good candidate for this competition. See [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) with
  comparisons with other databases